# VS2022 throws error message 'file already exists' on dbml file addition

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2022

I had to add a dbml file in C# Windows Form application. On adding a new dbml file, VS2022 throws error message indicating that the file is already present even though the file is newly created and has a unique name.
Please share your inputs in case you have faced similar issue in VS2022.

> A file with name 'DataClasses1.dbml.layout' already exists. Please give a unique name to the item you are adding, or delete the existing first.

Comment: Error image removed and error text update in query as suggested.

Comment: did you ever figure this one out? struggling with same issue now